# Macbook Pro does not mount printers after adding them

Tags: mojave, printing

I have a Macbook pro here running MacOS Mojave. When trying to add a network printer, I select the correct driver, and click add nothing and happens. There is no record of the printer being listed under the pane. There is no error message and when going into a browser to try and print there is no record of it there either.

Has anybody else experienced this?

Comment: Is your printer air print enabled?

Comment: How long did you wait? My current printer takes up to two minutes to be added.